# Hecke Operator- sum over divisors of a number

Tags: summation, number-theory

I am trying to write out the Hecke Operator; however, I don't know how to sum over all divisors of an integer. Could someone please give me some advice how to do that. Below is the Hecke Operator definition I use:

$$T_NZ(\tau)= \sum_{d|N}\sum_{\kappa=0}^{d-1}Z\left(\frac{N\tau/d +\kappa}{d}\right)$$

Many thanks!!

Comment: E.g. `Sum[f[d], {d, Divisors[122]]`

Comment: Thank you!! I got it..

Answer (score 2):

`DivisorSum[]` can be used for this:

```
hecke[f_, n_Integer?Positive, τ_] := 
      DivisorSum[n, Sum[Function[τ, f][(n τ/# + b)/#], {b, 0, # - 1}] &]
```

For example:

```
hecke[KleinInvariantJ[τ], 3, τ]
   KleinInvariantJ[τ/3] + KleinInvariantJ[3 τ] +
   KleinInvariantJ[(1 + τ)/3] + KleinInvariantJ[(2 + τ)/3]
```